# Why bootstrap 3 only works in symfony2 dev mode, not in prod mode?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

just a silly quick question, i set up Bootstrap 3 follow by the steps from [here](http://mossco.co.uk/symfony-2/symfony-2-and-bootstrap-3-assetic-config-and-base-html-template-file/). It works at dev mode but no prod mode. Just want to ask what kind of problem can cause that? If need codes, I will show it later. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with "It not works in prod mode" - what does exactly not working? more information would be helpful.

Comment: Did you run `app/console --env=prod assets:install web´ and ´app/console --env=prod assetic:dump´ on production server ?

Comment: You all right, I have to dump assets in prod mod. Cause I set "use_controller" as false. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dump your assets on production. During development, assetic converts the assets each time you request them. Because that'll cost some time, it doesn't do this in production. So, you have to dump the assets (which means assetic only converts the assets once) in production.

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Read more about this in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment

Comment: Thanks, it's solved! In dev, I dont wanna dump the assets, it makes a lot files. But in prod, it seems better to use dump, its faster